# Serving Landing page using nginx. Unable to get '/' to work while other urls are working fine

Tags: nginx, web-server

I am trying to set up a landing page for my site( say example.com) and I want to serve my own html as the page to load when someone types 'example.com' on their browser. I am using nginx as my webserver but unable to achieve this properly. I always get the default 'welcome to nginx' page instead of my html.

Here is my nginx conf:

```
    #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  1;


    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       mime.types;
       # include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;


        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;


        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  example.com;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;


            location / {
                root /data/www;
                index test.html;
             }
            location /images{
               root /data;
             }


            error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
              root   html;
            }

    }
}
```

This is working fine for these urls:

```
example.com/images/example.jpg, 
example.com/test.html
```

But I am expecting example.com to pick up test.html since I gave the index module in the location '/' block. But example.com just returns the default 'Welcome to nginx' page. Can anyone help me find what is going wrong in this? I want to host the landing page without any url appendages to example.com. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the root and index lines outside the "location" block:

```
...
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

root /data/www;
index test.html;

location / {
...
```

Comment: Okay. Off to the gym now. Will come back and tell you if it worked. :) thanks for the prompt response. I don't know what is wrong with my config though.

Comment: The preferred way is to have `root` directive on the `server` level, and then use `alias` inside location blocks to change those locations' directories. When using `alias /var/www/dir1;` inside `location /example`, the URI `/example/file1` will send the file `/var/www/dir1/file1`, that is, the `/example` part of the URI is stripped.

Comment: @Cyber: Your solution works.. But I think I still did not get proper clarity on why I have to do this and why my config does not work. Will be very helpful if you can point me to an appropriate resource which I can go through to gain more understanding. Thanks, mate. :)